# Application Runs in IIS 7.0 2.0 App Pool, but not in 1.1 App Pool

Tags: .net, iis-7, windows-server-2008-r2

I have an application that I'm migrating from Server 2003 to Server 2008r2.  The application was written in .NET 1.1.  I've installed .NET 1.1 on the 2008r2 box.  The application runs in 2.0 (with errors), but doesn't run in 1.1.

I've created an App Pool for ASP.NET 1.1:

> [image: Application Pool Screenshot]

I've used that App Pool for the application:

> [image: Application Settings]

And I have allowed ASP.NET 1.1 in the ISAPI and CGI Restrictions:

> [image: ISAPI and CGI Restrictions screenshot]

However, I get a page cannot be displayed message:

> [image: Page cannot be displayed screenshot]

As I mentioned, if I switch app pools, the website will render (with errors).

I'm not seeing any errors logged in the windows logs.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There were numerous issues with the application preventing it from running on framework 2.0.  The solution to the overall issue was to address the numerous small issues with the application. This enabled us to roll the application out for testing on the 2.0 framework.

Given that the new application server was SQL 2008, it made sense to go through with this upgrade anyway.  Unfortunately it took a little more work than we had hoped.